# UISearchBar changes background when selecting text field

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I want background of `UISearchBar` to be black, but when selecting the text field, it slides up and changes the background to gray:

Default:

[image]

--

When selected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set black colour in background of `UISearchBar` then try it ..

```
UISearchBar *searchbar=[[UISearchBar alloc]init];
searchbar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchBar` has a `translucent` property, make sure it's set to false.

Without more information, this is my best guess as to why this is happening: your tint color is black, but it's translucent, when it's not selected it shows as black because there's no view underneath, but when it's selected, a white view moves behind it, causing the black translucent to look gray.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```